# How to change the username displayed within terminal window on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, terminal, account, linux-mint

I am trying to change my current username on Linux Mint that shows up when I open a terminal window.

Currently:

john@myLinux

I want to change to:

gary@myLinux

I have tried:

(1) Start -> Settings -> Account Detail and altered the 'name' field.

(2) The steps mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

(3) Altering the passwd file: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

Option #3 seems to affect the username displaying in the terminal window but causes issues with logging in(my password becomes incorrect).

How can I successfully change the username that is displayed in my terminal window on Linux Mint OS?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes you are using `bash`, and might not work for a different shell.

This will only change the terminal prompt text, it will not update your user account or change any other system files.

1. in a terminal type `DEFAULT=$PS1`
2. next type `PS1='gary@\h\$ '`
3. last of all, if you want to return to your default prompt type `PS1=$DEFAULT`

Note 1: Make sure to save these settings in your `.bashrc` file under the home directory to have changes persist across terminal sessions.

Note 2: In step 2, `\h` tells the bash prompt to print out the computer hostname, the `\$` prints out show the (#) symbol if you're ROOT otherwise show the ($) symbol.

More information can be found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/

Comment: This answered my question.